# Scipy interpolation.griddata freezes when called on a particular point

Tags: python, scipy, linear-interpolation

I am trying to perform a simple 2D linear interpolation with Scipy interpolation.griddata but it behaves in a strange way : it runs forever and the computation can't be interrupted (100% CPU, RAM doesn't move, and I have to kill the process).
The data + coordinates that should be interpolated are located inside a polygon. At first, I tried to use a meshgrid containing only points located inside that polygon, but it didn't solve the problem.

I also tried to reduce to a very tiny interpolation grid (10*10), but it kept on freezing.

Then I tried to interpolate the meshgrid points one by one and found out that only some of them were causing the issue, and I can't figure out why.

Here is a sample of the code :

```
# Sets negative levels to zero
x_a = x_a.clip(min = 0)
coordinate = np.array(coordinate)

# Experiment zone polygon.
if city == "sf":
    zone = [[-122.397752, 37.799137],
            [-122.423329, 37.795746],
            [-122.418523, 37.772886],
            [-122.39243, 37.793982]]
    zone.append(zone[0]) # to close the polygon.

# Background map extent lat/long coordinates.
x_min_map = min([xy[0] for xy in zone])
x_max_map = max([xy[0] for xy in zone])
y_min_map = min([xy[1] for xy in zone])
y_max_map = max([xy[1] for xy in zone])

def IsPointInsidePolygon(x, y, poly):
    n = len(poly)
    inside = False

    p1x, p1y = poly[0]
    for i in range(n + 1):
        p2x, p2y = poly[i % n]
        if y > min(p1y, p2y):
            if y <= max(p1y, p2y):
                if x <= max(p1x, p2x):
                    if p1y != p2y:
                        xinters = (y - p1y) * (p2x - p1x) / (p2y - p1y) + p1x
                    if p1x == p2x or x <= xinters:
                        inside = not inside
        p1x, p1y = p2x, p2y

    return inside

# Creates a mesh grid adapted to the sf zone, on which to interpolate.
N = 10
xi = np.linspace(x_min_map, x_max_map, N)
yi = np.linspace(y_min_map, y_max_map, N)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
xi, yi = xi.flatten(), yi.flatten()
all_points = np.vstack((xi, yi)).T
delete_index = []
for i, point in enumerate(all_points):
    if not IsPointInsidePolygon(point[0], point[1], zone):
        delete_index.append(i)

grid_points = np.delete(all_points, delete_index, axis = 0)

# Interpolation
zi = interpolate.griddata(coordinate, x_a, grid_points, method = "linear")
```

The "coordinate" variable is an array that contains approximately 1e4 float coordinates that are located inside the "zone" polygon.

The x_min_map etc. are the computed max and min x, y values of the polygon, so that the original meshgrid is the smallest rectangle containing the whole polygon.

Any advice will be appreciated !

Comment: Try upgrading to a newer scipy version.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already up to date.
I should add that this script (minus the meshgrid reduction to the polygon zone) seemed to work on a friend's computer (at least it finished in a short timed). I don't know precisely the differences between our configurations.

Comment: If you are up-to-date, `print scipy.__version__` will print `0.14.0` --- is this the case? It's not possible to say much without knowing what's in the `coordinate` and `x_a` arrays. You should either save them to a file and upload that somewhere, or provide a short code demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Thank you for insisting on the version check. 
I was only using apt-get to check this out, which was obviously not the good way to do it.

The script runs well with SciPy 0.14.0.